# Firewall rule in Windows 7 that allows MAC Address Proxy Authentication

Tags: windows-7, firewall, mac-address

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and I', using Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

My proxy server uses MAC Address as it's authentication scheme. When the firewall is in disabled state, I can connect to internet using the proxy without any problem. However, when the firewall is in enabled state, I can't connect to internet through the proxy. My suspicion is that somehow the firewall cloaked my MAC Address info.

Looking at the firewall advanced settings, there are a bunch of rules in there, and I'm sure that one of them needs to be disabled (or enabled) in order for me to get through the proxy MAC address authentication. Which rule(s) should I enable/disable?

Comment: What proxy are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way the firewall can cloak your MAC address.  If it did your machine wouldn't communicate with anything.  There must be something else going on with the proxy that the firewall doesn't like.